# GTK+ - Refresh a scrolledwindow

Tags: c, gtk, refresh, scrolledwindow

I have a scrolledwindow inside a main window. I want to when i click button refresh, content of scrolledwindow will refresh automatic.This is callback to button

```
vbox = gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 5);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), vbox);
gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button_refresh), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(button_re), NULL);
```

there is callback function:

```
 void button_re(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data){
connectserver(myFile, numof);//connect to server and get information
if(numof > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i< numof; i++){
        hbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
        sprintf(buffer, "%s", myFile[i].name);
        label = gtk_label_new(buffer);
        button_down = gtk_button_new_with_label("Download");
        gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button_down), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(button_download), (gpointer ) i);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), label, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button_down, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    }
}else if(numof == 0){
    label = gtk_label_new("Have nothing on server");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, TRUE, FALSE, 2);
}
```

But when i click button, there are nothing happed. What should i do?
I'm so sorry because my english is not good.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `button_re` you are creating new labels, buttons, etc.  These won't show up until you call `gtk_widget_show` on them, somehow.  Somewhere in the initialization of your program - `main()` perhaps - probably you call `gtk_widget_show_all` on your main window, which recursively "show"s everything within it.  But these new objects won't be shown until you explicitly request that they are.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you very muchhhhh, gcbeninson, I resolved this problem. :)

Comment: @ĐăngphươngNguyễn If the answer helped you, do not forget to click the "accept" button next to the answer.

Comment: ohh, Sorry, I will remember :D

Comment: I have more trouble, When i click button again (when i want to update content from server), The new content adding to tail of scrolled window, the old content still there, above new content. How can i delete old content? @gcbenison

Comment: You probably could find and destroy the previously-added elements, but if that's the kind of behavior you need, you should look into the GTK list store and related structures; they're designed for that type of use.  Search for `gtktreeview` and start from there.